# Java integer is equal to character?

Tags: java

I apologize if this question is a bit simplistic, but I'm somewhat puzzled as to why my professor has made the following the statement:

*Notice that read() returns an integer value. Using an int as a return type allows read() to use -1 to indicate that it has reached the end of the stream. **You will recall from your introduction to Java that an int is equal to a char which makes the use of the -1 convenient.***

The professor was referencing the following sample code:

```
public class CopyBytes {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;

    try {
        in = new FileInputStream("Independence.txt");
        out = new FileOutputStream("Independence.txt");
        int c;

        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);
        }
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

This is an advanced Java course, so obviously I've taken a few introductory courses prior to this one. Maybe I'm just having a "blonde moment" of sorts, but I'm not understanding in what context an integer could be equal to a character when making comparisons. The instance method read() returns an integer value when it comes to EOF. That I understand perfectly.

Can anyone shed light on the statement in bold?

Comment: What do you think a "character" is??  It's just a number which, by convention, corresponds to a particular glyph.

Comment: `97 == 'a'`.  Basically if you cast `97` to `char` (`(char)97`) it will return `a`

Comment: Sounds like I was right after all. Just another blonde moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, chars is a more specific type of int.  I can write.

```
char c = 65;
```

This code prints out "A".  I need the cast there so Java knows I want the character representation and not the integer one.

```
public static void main(String... str) {
    System.out.println((char) 65);
}
```

You can look up the int to character mapping in an [ASCII table.](http://www.asciitable.com)

And per your teacher, int allows for more values.  Since -1 isn't a character value, it can serve as a flag value.

Comment: Actually what happens here is a narrowing primitive conversion from `int` to `char`, since we're assigning an `int` literal to a variable of type `char`. This is covered in [JLS §5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3).

Comment: True.  I was trying to explain it colloquially.

Comment: Right, I just added that comment for the sake of completeness. +1 anyhow.

Comment: int to character mappings should be looked up from a Unicode table.

Answer (score 1):

To a computer a character is just a number (that may at some point be mapped to a picture of a letter for display to the user). Languages usually have a special character type to distinguish between "just a number" and "a number that refers to a character", but inside, it's still just some sort of integer.

The reason why `read()` returns an `int` is to have "one extra value" to represent EOF. All the values of `char` are already defined to mean something else, so it uses a larger type to get more values.

Comment: FYI, not all languages treat "character" types as just a different kind of integer.  C, Java, and other languages in the C family do.  Pascal and Ada do not--you will get errors if you try to assign an `integer` variable to a `character` value without going through some additional syntax.

Comment: @ajb: It's still an integer inside. There just aren't any implicit conversions.

Answer (score 1):

It means your professor has been spending too much time programming in C.  The definition of `read` for `InputStream` (and `FileInputStream`) is:

> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned.

(See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read())

A `char` in Java, on the other hand, represents a Unicode character, and is treated as an integer in the range 0 to 65535.  (In C, a `char` is an 8-bit integral value, either 0 to 255 or -128 to 127.)

Please note that in Java, a `byte` is actually an integer in the range -128 to 127; but the definition of `read` has been specified to avoid the problem, by decreeing that it will return 0 to 255 anyway.  The javadoc is using "byte" in a loose sense here.

Comment: I don't think my professor is the only one spending time in C lol. I'm actually finishing the last semester of my undergrad, and my prior 3 years were spent coding in C/C++. This is my 3rd Java course and I'm still trying to wrap my head around some of the inconsistencies.

Comment: I do not find the expression `char c = 65` to be an inconsistency.  How is that expression any different from `int i = 3.14159f` ?

Answer (score 1):

The char data type in Java is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

The int data type in Java is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive).

Since char *cannot* be negative (a number between 0 and 65,535) and an int *can* be negative, the possible values returned from the method is -1 (to signify nothing left) to 65,535 (max value of a char).

Answer (score 0):

What your professor is referring to the fact that characters are just integers used in a special context.  If we ignore Unicode and other encoding types and focus on the old days of ASCII, there was an ASCII table (http://www.asciitable.com/).  A string of characters is really just a sequence of integers, for example, TUV would be 84 followed by 85 followed by 86.

The 'char' type is an integer internally in the JVM and is more or less a hint that this integer should only be used in a character context.

You can even cast between them.

```
char a = (char) 65;
int i = (int) 'A';
```

Those two variables hold the same data in memory, but the compiler and JVM treat them slightly differently.

Because of this, read() returns an integer instead of char so as to allow a -1, which is not a valid character code.  Values other than -1 can be cast to a char, while -1 indicates EOF.

Of course, Unicode changes all of this with multi-byte character and code points.  I'll leave that as an exercise to you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the professor means but what it all comes down to is computers only understand 1's and 0's we don't understand 1's and 0's all that we'll so we use a code system first Morris code then ascii now utf -16 ... It varies from computer to computer how accurate numbers(int) is.you know in the real world int is infinate they just keep counting.char also has a size.in utf _16 let's just say it's 16 bits (I will let you read up on that) so if char and int both take 16 bits as the professor says they are the same (size) and reading 1 char is the same as 1int . By the way to be politically correct char is infinite as well.Chinese characters French characters and the character I just made up but can't post cause its not supported.so think of the code system for int and char. -1 int is eof char.(eof = end of file) good luck, I hope this helped.what I don't understand is reading and writing to the same file?

Comment: I think you meant "Morse Code".  I think the history and evolution of data encodings is rather a bit more substantial than you let on.  For example, you made no mention of EBCDIC.

Comment: True and utf-16 isn't always 16 but sometimes it is.